# Solution for exception org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.util.BadBlockException: unable to decrypt block

Tags: java

I am using RSA encryption. I am able to encrypt my data using RSA public key but not able to decrypt using RSA private key. Can anybody help me on this?

Getting exception like shown below when doing decryption using private key.

> org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.util.BadBlockException: unable to
>   decrypt block at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.getOutput(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(Unknown
>   Source) at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164) at
>   com.example.demo.encdec.RSAEncDecTest.decryptUsingRSAKey(RSAEncDecTest.java:42)
>   at com.example.demo.encdec.RSAEncDecTest.main(RSAEncDecTest.java:25)
>   Caused by: org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: data
>   wrong at org.bouncycastle.crypto.encodings.OAEPEncoding.dec

Comment: Please provide a code example showing the problem and the full exception.

Comment: Brought exception and comment into the question. It's usually best to edit your question and include additional information rather than posting it as comments.